# Redefinition of enumerator, previous declaration of properties and duplicate interface errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In my project, I have a sub project.Both have a dependency on reachability class.

There was duplicate symbol error coming.

So I unlinked the Reachabilty of my project from and was depending on the Reachabilty of sub project because that will get compiled first.

Now I have only one copy of Reachability but here also I get Redefinition of enums, previous declaration of properties and duplicate interface errors.

All these errors are too much for me to gulp at the same time.

I am just trying to integrate the my module in an existing big project.

How should I get rid of this situation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic iOS problem. What is the format of your sub project? Do you have access to the code? Can you make Reachability public from the sub-project?

In the absolute worse case, you can rename the the Reachability symbol names in your project. I've done that before ... it hurts my pride but it's sometimes necessary.

Comment: yes I have access to the code. The thing is now I have obnly one Reachabilty, I unlinked the one in the outer project.

I already had two reachability in sub project I renamed one in it.
But when I included this in outer one.. there was another reachability..I didnt wanted to rename again so I removed it from projecty.
But the import statements for outer project are hurting as they re import after sub project has compiled!

Comment: Not really following. Make sure to do a "Clean Build Folder ..." in Xcode when changing crazy dependencies so there are no surprises: SHIFT-ALT-CMD-K

Comment: I placed everything in common directory and kept only one version.
Also instead of using a subproject I put the source in it.
No more static library!
Things seem fine now :)